# Could I use JNI interfaces in my C++ code when using the dart:ffi in flutter?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, ffi, flutter-desktop

Now I load my C++ code by:

```
final DynamicLibrary nativeAddLib =
  Platform.isAndroid
    ? DynamicLibrary.open("libnative_add.so")
    : DynamicLibrary.process();
```

but the `JNI_OnLoad` in my .cpp file is not executed:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
  LOGI("JNI_OnLoad!");
}
```

Comment: Automatic execution of `JNI_OnLoad` only happens when a JVM is instructed to load the DLL. It seems you are loading the DLL from Dart.

Comment: `It seems you are loading the DLL from Dart`
yes, it's true

Answer (score 0):

As @Botje said, it seems that the `DynamicLibrary.open` does not instruct JVM to load the library.

Finally I add an extra `.so` library to encapsulate the interaction with `JNI`, and load it via `System.loadLibrary` in java.